# Por que formulário não envia?

Tags: html, formulário, post

Já olhei todo o código e não consigo achar onde está o erro. O formulário nao envia os dados quando clico no botão enviar.

```
<section id="inscricao" class="bg-light-gray">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                    <h2 class="section-heading">Inscrição</h2>
                    <h3 class="section-subheading text-muted">Preencha os seguintes campos e tenha sua vaga garantida.</h3>
                    <form action="control/setcadastro.php" method="post">
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <label for="name">Nome *</label>
                            <input class="form-control" name="nome" type="text" placeholder="Digite seu nome" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <label for="idade">Idade *</label>
                            <input class="form-control" name="idade" type="number" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <label>Sexo</label><br>
                            <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="sexo" value="M">Masculino</label>
                            <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="sexo" value="F">Feminino</label>
                        </div>
                        <br><br><br><br>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <label for="email">E-mail</label>
                            <input class="form-control" name="email" type="email" placeholder="Digite seu e-mail">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <label for="cpf">CPF (apenas  números) *</label>
                            <input class="form-control" name="cpf" type="text" maxlength="14" placeholder="Digite número de CPF" OnKeyPress="formatar('###.###.###-##', this)" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <label>RG (apenas números)</label><br>
                            <input class="form-control" name="rg" type="text" placeholder="Digite número de RG">
                        </div>
                        <br><br><br><br>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <label for="ocup">Ocupação</label>
                            <input class="form-control" name="ocup" type="text" placeholder="Informe sua ocupação">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <label>Nacionalidade</label><br>
                            <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="nac" value="B">Brasileira</label>
                            <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="nac" value="O">Outra</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <label for="birth">Nascimento (apenas números)</label>
                            <input class="form-control" name="birth" type="text" maxlength="14" placeholder="Digite Data de Nascimento" OnKeyPress="formatar('##-##-####', this)" >
                        </div><br><br>
                        <br><br>
                        <input class="page-scroll btn btn-xl" type="submit">
                    </form>
                    <br><a href="listaCadastrados.php"><h4>Consulte a lista de incritos ou edite seus dados</h4></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Aparece algum erro?

Comment: Adicione no <form enctype="multipart/form-data"> e tente o envio pra ver...

Comment: Possui algum código javascript na página?

Comment: há algum javascript que possa estar a bloquear o formulário?

Comment: Você preencheu todos os campos obrigatórios antes de tentar enviar o formulário?